# Getting Error in connection with mysql from php?

Tags: php, mysql, connection

i am new to php and getting error whole connecting to mysql as i have my sql install in my virtual machine having ip 192.168.1.104 and i am using this mysql in my machine server 2003 having ip 192.168.1.102 an i am successfully using it on server using mysql client but on server when i am trying to access mysql for php my making connection i am getting error...

here is the connection i mande for mysql from php,

```
<?php



$port = "3306";

$server = "192.168.1.104:".$port;

$dbname ="VideoResume";

$user = "root";

$pass = "nagios";



$conn = mysql_connect ($server, $user, $pass) or die ("Connection Error or Bad Port");



mysql_select_db($dbname) or die("Missing Database");



?
```

>

the error as i attach file with mysqlerror name

hopes to listen from you soon thanks in advance

Regards,

-syed mohsin raza[image: Eror in Connection are in this image]

Comment: Search for the error message you got online and you will find a solution quick.

Answer (score 3):

the error itself is clear that you need to reset root's password:

The commands are

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

you might want to take a look at

[MySQL root user password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: There is also an ini setting that mysql accepts old passwords IIRC. And how should one execute that SQL you've posted if she/he can not connect to the database?

Comment: thanks a lot hakre for pointing it out , will definitely remember that the next time I opt to answer

Comment: @saya so i will update it after logging from root user at terminal and then run this query ?

Comment: remove old_passwords flag from my.cnf file

Comment: @saya i searched this file and find two file in which i freez this old pasw line with # so that it would work but error is same ?? i also restart mysql service

Comment: check this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_old-passwords